# Perl: performance hit with reading multiple files

Tags: perl

I was wondering what is better in this case?

I have to read in thousands of files. I was thinking of opening into each file and reading one and closing it. Or cat all the files into one file and read that.

Suggestions? This is all in Perl.

Comment: Do whatever you like, [profiling](http://p3rl.org/Devel::NYTProf) will reveal that the program spends most of its time processing the lines, so its not worth to optimise the opening part.

Comment: To a first approximation, the more opcodes executed, the longer it takes to run. This is only a rough approximation to reality, but it is more true than it is false: the inner interpreter dispatch loop will then dominate.

Comment: daxim: How can you know that? Gordon did not describe what is done with the files. Imagine he has 1000s of files like `a\nb\nc\n` and just wants to count lines (synthetic example). The processing would be much faster than the disk head running for the files, thus reading many different files would cause a major overhead. @Gordon: Give more details for us to tell better if it will make any difference.

Comment: thanks guys, i am doing some data extract from each of these unique files. i did both cases and it's about the same time. i will have to optimize how i'm processing the lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shouldn't make that much of a difference.  This sounds like premature optimization to me.

Answer (score 2):

If the time for `cat`ing all files into one bigger file doesn't matter it will be faster (only when reading the file sequentially which is the default).

Of course if the process is taken into account it'll be much slower because you have to read, write and read again.

In general reading one file of 1000M should be faster than reading 100 files of 10M because for the 100 files you'll need to look for the metadata.

As tchrist says the performance difference might not be important. I think it depends on the type of file (e.g. for a huge number of files which are very small it would differ much more) and the overall performance of your system and its storage.

Comment: Sounds correct. If you're reading each file multiple times, you might benefit from 1 `cat * >bigfile` and then reading that file often; but if it's one time, it won't make much difference.

Comment: Catting them together requires context-switch time, no matter how clever the buffer cache system is.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `cat *` can fail if number of files is greater than your `ulimit -n` value. So sequential read can actually be safer.
Also, consider using `opendir` and `readdir` instead of `glob` if all your files are located in the same dir.

Comment: BTW, Perl’s internal `glob` function should have no NCARGS limitation.

Comment: Hm, you are right, I don't know why I thought it would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the files sequentially. Perl's file i/o functions are pretty thin wrappers around native file i/o calls in the OS, so there isn't much point in fretting about performance from simple file i/o.